# WCF 'BasicHttpBinding' with a XML Parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I am new to web development and [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation). I am tasked to create a WCF application/service that can be accessed by other technologies as well. Thus I ended up with [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx). I will have a XML parameter. Here is my code:

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", UriTemplate:="")> _
Function ReceiveMessage( _
             ByVal input As Stream) _
As String

Public Function ReceiveMessage(ByVal input As System.IO.Stream) As String Implements IService.ReceiveMessage
    Dim rssDS As New DataSet
    Dim MsgStrHeader As String = ""

    Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(input)
    rssDS.ReadXml(sr)

    For Each RssRow As DataRow In rssDS.Tables(0).Rows
        MsgStrHeader = RssRow.Item(0).ToString & " -- " & RssRow.Item(2).ToString & " Unread Messages"
    Next

    Return MsgStrHeader
End Function
```

---

Any concrete example on how do I go about this? How do I test this one? Using a simple HTML page.

Comment: stackoverflow code window fail.

Comment: You mention the basicHttpBinding - yet you have <WebInvoke> on your method - that's REST using the webHttpBinding..... so which one are you using in the end?

Comment: Also, do you really want to use streaming for this call? Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just pass in the RSS as a string? Or better yet: pass in just the URL where to get the RSS and not the RSS itself?

Comment: well honestly I am a little confused of the concepts but I need make a webservice that can process HTTP POST (thus i think restful web service) sending XML to our call back URL.

just pass in the RSS as a string? I will take a look at this

Comment: Yes, if you want to HTTP POST something, then we're talking about REST - WCF supports that through the **webHttpBinding**.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem sending an XML parameter over WCF.

The easy work around is to convert the XML document to a string.

See: [Is there an issue sending XML via WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141863/is-there-an-issue-sending-xml-via-wcf)